# WatchOS: Pass data from one controller to another through "Next Page" segue

Tags: swift, segue, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I am loading 3 interfacecontrollers with WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers with contexts in my app.

Everything works just fine. However, I need to pass data from Page 1 to Page 2 on swipe. It seems there is not segue that I can use programmatically to create a new context or pass data another way.

How could I solve this? 
I don't want to create a singleton just for this. I know how to pass data in contexts with other segues, this question specifically relate to "Next Page" navigation on Watchkit. I couldn't find an answer so far.

Thanks!

Markus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between interface controllers in WatchKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403780/passing-data-between-interface-controllers-in-watchkit)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using contextForSegue in your first page?

```
override func contextForSegue(withIdentifier segueIdentifier: String) -> Any? {
    let myDate = "today"
    return myDate
}
```

Comment: This only works for push or modal segues. If you're using page-based navigation, `contextForSegue` isn't called. I have the same problem, and have not found any solution yet, so I'm working around it by using the ExtensionDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm been looking around for an answer for this question also..

NextPage Segue is similar to `UIPageViewController` in iOS. I have tried `contextForSegue(withIdentifier segueIdentifier: String)` but it is not getting called on swipe, and you can't give this segue an `identifier` in the storyboard.

The only way around it for me was to use `NotificationCenter`

In the first InterfaceController I post a notification with the object on `willDisappear`/`didDeactivate` doesn't really make a difference with watchOS and on the second InterfaceController I subscribed to it.

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("interface1WillDisappear"), object: context)
```

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(awake(withNotification:)), name: Notification.Name("interface1WillDisappear"), object: nil)
```

Add I added this func

```swift
func awake(withNotification notification: Notification) {
  guard let context = context as? MyContextObject else { return }
  print(context)
}
```

Finally don't forget to remove the observer

```swift
deinit {
  NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Hope this helps!